# Implement 3rd party application server for GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to create 3rd party application server for GCM. I had read it on internet but I did not got much information, so i am looking for help how to create third party application server for GCM.

As I read there are two type of server- HTTP and CCS. I want one way communication (i.e from cloud-to-device) therefore I will use HTTP.

If anybody knows how to implement or any resource then please let me know. I had read [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html) on this but still not get clear idea.

Answer (score 1):

Full tutorial here with PHP, MySQL & Android, I tried this before and it can work.
[http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/][1]

Your server just need a database to save app's token, and communicate with Cloud server to send message, that's all.